# While loop keeps printing out and not reading the next line

Tags: c++, printing, while-loop

This is my first simple program. It keeps printing out `Guess what it is.` non-stop and doesn't even ask for user input. (the next line of code.)
What is my mistake?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string userName;
    cout << "Hello there.\n";
    cout << "My name is TARS. \n";
    cout << "What is your name? \n";
    getline(std::cin, userName);
    cout << userName << ", let's play a game.\n";
    int secretNum;
    secretNum = rand() % 20 + 1;
    cout << "I'm thinking of a number between 1-20.\n";
    int Guess;
    bool conti = true;

    while (conti)

        cout << "Guess what it is. \n";
        cin >> Guess;   

        if (Guess == secretNum)
        {
            cout << "You read my mind!";
            conti = false;
        }
        if (Guess < secretNum)
        {
            cout << "That is too low.";
        }
        if (Guess > secretNum)
        {
            cout << "That is too high.";
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put the code that's supposed to repeat in curly braces. Your while loop only assumes the first line after `while (conti)`  is supposed to repeat, since you didn't tell it any different.

Comment: these downvotes are a bit unfaire. The OP said its his first program. be nice guys...remeber how you started..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `brackets`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string userName;
    cout << "Hello there.\n";
    cout << "My name is TARS. \n";
    cout << "What is your name? \n";
    getline(std::cin, userName);
    cout << userName << ", let's play a game.\n";
    int secretNum;
    secretNum = rand() % 20 + 1;
    cout << "I'm thinking of a number between 1-20.\n";
    int Guess;
    bool conti = true;

    while (conti)
    {

         cout << "Guess what it is. \n";
         cin >> Guess;

         if (Guess == secretNum)
         {
             cout << "You read my mind!";
             conti = false;
         }

         if (Guess < secretNum)
         {
             cout << "That is too low.";
         }

         if (Guess > secretNum)
         {
             cout << "That is too high.";
         }

    }

    return 0;

}
```

By default if you don't use them only the next line will be considered part of the while loop
in your case:

```
while (conti)
    cout << "Guess what it is. \n";
```

Answer (score 2):

you need braces for the while loop, or it will execute just that single statement forever.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (conti)
cout << "Guess what it is. \n";
```

is equivalent to:

```
while (conti)
{
   cout << "Guess what it is. \n";
}
```

i.e. the loop ends there. What you need is provide the opening and closing braces for the loop at the right place.

```
while (conti)
{
   cout << "Guess what it is. \n";
   cin >> Guess;
   if (Guess == secretNum)
   {
       cout << "You read my mind!";
       conti = false;
   }
   if (Guess < secretNum)
   {
       cout << "That is too low.";
   }
   if (Guess > secretNum)
   {
       cout << "That is too high.";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `missed the braces` for while loop. You may try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string userName;

    cout << "Hello there.\n";
    cout << "My name is TARS. \n";
    cout << "What is your name? \n";
    getline(std::cin, userName);
    cout << userName << ", let's play a game.\n";

    int secretNum;
    secretNum = rand() % 20 + 1;

    cout << "I'm thinking of a number between 1-20.\n";

    int Guess;
    bool conti = true;

    while (conti){

        cout << "Guess what it is. \n";
        cin >> Guess;

        if (Guess == secretNum)
        {
            cout << "You read my mind!";
            conti = false;
        }

        if (Guess < secretNum)
        {
            cout << "That is too low.";
        }

        if (Guess > secretNum)
        {
            cout << "That is too high.";
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing two `curly braces` to widen the scope of your while-loop. Note that without curly braces the scope of any loop in C++ will stop at the first semicolon. Here's a working solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

      string userName;

      cout << "Hello there.\n";
      cout << "My name is TARS. \n";
      cout << "What is your name? \n";
      getline(std::cin, userName);

      cout << userName << ", let's play a game.\n";

      int secretNum;
      secretNum = rand() % 20 + 1;

      cout << "I'm thinking of a number between 1-20.\n";

      int Guess;
      bool conti = true;

      while (conti) 
      {  // <-- This curly brace was missing

          cout << "Guess what it is. \n";
          cin >> Guess;

          if (Guess == secretNum)
          {
              cout << "You read my mind!";
              conti = false;
          }

          if (Guess < secretNum)
          {
              cout << "That is too low.";
          }

          if (Guess > secretNum)
          {
            cout << "That is too high.";
          }


      } // <-- This curly brace was also missing

      return 0;

}
```